# Center item content but leave bullet to the right

Tags: align, lists

How can I center the text (includes math) in a list (itemize or enumerate) item but leave the bullet to the left?

What I want:

```
| (i)                Lorem Ipsum Dolor $E=mc^2$                       |
```

What I get:

```
|                  (i) Lorem Ipsum Dolor $E=mc^2$                     |
```

I tried both `\begin{center}` and `\centering`. I also tried to add `\hfill` around the content.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
% First try
\item \begin{center}
    text
\end{center}
% Second try
\item \centering
    text
\end{enumerate}
% Third try
\item \begin{center} \hfill
    text
\hfill\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome! What does `\item \hfill
    text
\hfill\mbox{}` give?

Comment: Would the item text fit on a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a simple `\makebox[\linewidth]`, since by default, the contents of a \makebox  is centred in the box width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item \makebox[\linewidth]
   {Some text}
\item\makebox[\linewidth]{$\begin{aligned}[t]
  a & =b + c \\
a' & = b' + c'
\end{aligned}$}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]